# rails 2 slow to start after rubygems upgrade

Tags: ruby-on-rails

ruby 1.8.7, rails 2.3.8, rubygems 1.6.0

i think this started happening after upgrading to rubygems 1.6.0 (i can't say for sure, i haven't touched this project in over two months). script/server and script/console are both extremely slow to start; around 15-18s, which is significantly slower than it used to be. mongrel and webrick are about the same. i know it's not my gems as i put some debug lines in environment.rb after the config.gem lines and they appear to load almost immediately.

oddly enough, rails 3 applications start up just fine. i don't even know where to start looking for the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I'm seeing the same issue with 1.8.7 (p248), Rails 2.3.10, and RubyGems 1.6.1.  The slowness immediately showed up for this application directly after the RubyGems update.  And, this is a project which is worked on multiple times per week.  Skimming the [RubyGems Tracker](http://rubyforge.org/tracker/?group_id=126), I don't see any other mentions of this issue.

Comment: did you also have to add `require 'thread'` to boot.rb or environment.rb to get your rails 2 server to start?

Comment: Hmm.. no, not for this application, the `require 'thread'` wasn't necessary.  A `./script/server` boots into WEBrick without any issue after the upgrade.

Answer (score 1):

I'm still seeing the same issue with 1.8.7, rails 2.3.11, rubygems 1.7.2.

Refer to this ticket.

http://rubyforge.org/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=29116&group_id=126&atid=575

I downgraded back to rubygems 1.3.7 to temporarily fix the problem.